# Baer sum of $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am working on trying to figure out the third extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $\mathbb{Z}_3$, I know one is $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and the neutral element (with respect to baer sum) $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$. I know from $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_3)\cong\mathbb{Z}_3$. So there is another extension availiable. I know therefore that $\mathbb{Z}_9+_B\mathbb{Z}_9$ must result in another extension but I am running into trouble trying to recognise how it looks like. Let our extension be
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}_3\xrightarrow{3}\mathbb{Z}_9\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{Z}_3\to 0$$
I know for the baer sum we have that the module we're after is the quotient of 
$$X=\{a\oplus b:\mathbb{Z}_9\oplus\mathbb{Z}_9:\pi(a)=\pi(b)\}$$
and
$$N=\{3n\oplus -3n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_3\}$$
That is our baer sum is $X/N$. All dandy so far, I have determined that 
$$X=3\mathbb{Z}_9\oplus3\mathbb{Z}_9 \cup(3\mathbb{Z}_9+1)\oplus(3\mathbb{Z}_9+1)\cup(3\mathbb{Z}_9+2)\oplus(3\mathbb{Z}_9+2)$$
Which is hardly pretty but this comes from $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$ if and only if $a=b+3n$ for some $n$.

Our $N$ is easier to determine as we get
$$N=\{(0,0),(3,-3),(6,-6)\}$$
or
$$N=\{(0,0),(3,6),(6,3)\}$$
This of course gives us $27/3=9$ elements in our module, I have checked on paper and even used programs and from what I can see it seems to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_9$ which makes no sense to me so I probably did some screwup along the way. The isomorphism I found would be $\phi(1)=1\oplus 1$ and it'll generate all 9 elements. I have even checked the orders of elements and then coincide with all orders of $\mathbb{Z}_9$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One needn't perform the Baer sum explicitly. If one has a SEC of the form $0\to \Bbb Z_3\to M\to \Bbb Z_3\to 0$ then one can conclude that $M$ has order $9$, so it must be $\Bbb Z_3^2$ of $\Bbb Z_9$, which are the only groups of order $9$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff This doesn't tell you why there are $3$ extensions, up to isomorphism of group extensions.

Comment: @Christoph That's true, but that can be handled by calculating the order of the extensions group as the OP did. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation are correct. The last extension is still isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_9$. By the way, in a short exact sequence like this, the order of the middle group is the product of the order, and you should know that up to isomorphism there are only two (abelian) groups of order 9.

Note that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ classifies the extensions of $A$ by $B$ up to isomorphism *of extensions*, but not up to isomorphism.

In other words, can you find the vertical arrow with (?) here :
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>>>\mathbb{Z}_3@>\times 3>>\mathbb{Z}_9@>\times 2>>\mathbb{Z}_3@>>>0\\
@.@|@V?VV@|@.\\
0@>>>\mathbb{Z}_3@>\times 3>>\mathbb{Z}_9@>\times 1>>\mathbb{Z}_3@>>>0
\end{CD}
$$

There is no such map (?). This mean that the two short exact sequences above define two different classes of extension in $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_3)$, and of course the trivial extension define the third one.

Comment: Hmmmm ah yes, good lord I keep forgetting that

Comment: Would you happen to know an extension that is simple to identify where I could illustrate baer sum and get something that looks more different?

Comment: For $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_4)\simeq\mathbb{Z}_4$ you get 3 different abelian groups. The one that is twice a generator is maybe "different"... What to you think ?

Comment: I gotta do the hard work to see how it looks :) Unless you could just do a quick show of it but I'll just do the brunt work then.

Comment: Just note that there is a short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow Z_4\rightarrow Z_8\oplus Z_2\rightarrow Z_4\rightarrow 0$$ where the left map is $n\mapsto (2n,n)$ and the right map is $(a,b)\mapsto a+2b$. This should appear as the baer sum of $$0\rightarrow Z_4\rightarrow Z_{16}\rightarrow Z_4\rightarrow 0$$ with itself.